# Code Block for Calculate Field Excluding "No Data" Values in a Feature Class in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I am trying to calculate a field (`NAT_RE_MI`) by simply adding three other fields (`FOR_FISH`, `MINING`, `FARM_EMP`) together.

Some of the fields have a no data value of `-98` or `-99`.

What code would I use to exclude those from the calculation in the Field Calculator for ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` to check the value of each field, and skip that value if it's one of your "no data" values.  You can add other "no data" values to the `no_data` list to skip those as well.

Expression:

```py
skip_nodata(!FOR_FISH!, !MINING!, !FARM_EMP!)
```

Code Block:

```py
def skip_nodata(val1, val2, val3):
    no_data = [-98, -99]
    x = 0
    if val1 not in no_data:
        x += val1
    if val2 not in no_data:
        x += val2
    if val3 not in no_data:
        x += val3
    return x
```

[image]

[image]